# load more than one page in a page dynamically

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a website written in c#, ASP.NET. I want to load pages in right div, according to links in left menu dynamically.  But I don't know where to start, which control etc..
Help me please..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the iframe tag on the right hand side to contain the dynamically loaded page and then just specificy that iframe's name property  in the target property for the links on the right hand side.

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <a href='www.reddit.com/r/jquery' target='contentFrame'>first Link</a> <br/>
     <a href='www.reddit.com/r/javascript' target='contentFrame'>Second Link</a>
   </td>
   <td>
               <iframe name='contentFrame' />
   </td>


    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this. An easy way would be to use `CSS` to create the layout (i.e. menu on the left, content on the right) and a `Masterpage`. A `Masterpage` is a page which is a template that other pages can use when they have aspects in common. Here, the menu on the left is common for all your pages, so you can create that layout in your Masterpage. Each page (e.g. `firstpage.aspx`) inherits that Masterpage and you can simply fill out the content on the right.

There are many CSS resources, but [this site](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/01/12/free-css-layouts-and-templates/) might help you get started with the layout aspect. More information on Masterpages can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Alternative methods include using AJAX to dynamically load pages. This may be a bit trickier depending on your design.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MasterPage` and ContentPages

Example:

#### MasterPage

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GlobalMaster.master.cs" Inherits="your masterpage class" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="menupanel">
    </div>
    <div id="mainpanel">
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="mainPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### ContentPage

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/path to your masterfile.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="page code behind" Inherits="page class" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <h3>
        Your cool content here
    </h3>
</asp:Content>
```

Note how you define the MasterPage you want to use by using the following attribute in the `Page` directive:

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/path to your masterfile.Master"
```

When you define a page like this, they are called **content pages**

The *content* of the page **has** to be defined inside `Content` controls:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainPlaceHolder" runat="server">
```

Also notice how the names have to match between the `MasterPage`'s `ContentPlaceHolder` ID and the `Content`'s `ContentPlaceHolderID` properties